# Class within a JAR is not accessible

Tags: java, jar, enums

I have created one java file from code, and bind it in the JAR file of the project. Now I am trying to use this JAR from another module of my project. All the classes are visible except the one that I have generated. 
Generated JAVA class is of ENUM type, and seems to be perfectly fine. What could be the possible reason for this?

output of jar tf  is :

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/
com/processing/
com/processing/
com/processing/commonutils/
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/csvUtil/
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/csvUtil/CsvHeaderConstants.class
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/csvUtil/CsvReader.class
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/csvUtil/CsvToEnumConverter.class
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/csvUtil/DataTypeEnum.class
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/main/
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/main/ErrorEnumGeneratorMain.class
Error Data1.csv
Error Data2.csv
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/Data1ErrorEnum.class
com/processing/commonutils/enumGenerator/Data2ErrorEnum.class
```

I am unable to access Data1ErrorEnum or Data2ErrorEnum classes . Rest all classes are visible. Data1ErrorEnum class looks like :

```
package com.processing.commonutils.enumGenerator;

public enum Data1ErrorEnum {

    DIE_1 ( "Data integrity error","FATAL" );

    private String errorType ;
    public String errorType() {
        return errorType;
    } 

    private String severity ;
    public String severity() {
        return severity;
    } 

    private Data1ErrorEnum  (String errorType,String severity)
    {
        this.errorType = errorType;
        this.severity = severity;
    }
}
```

Class from where I am trying to access this is given below :

```
package com.processing.commonutils.error;

import com.processing.commonutils.enumGenerator.*;

public class SystemException extends Exception {

    Data1ErrorEnum data1ErrorEnum ;

   }
```

Comment: Is it private to your Class ?

Comment: First of all, did you check the JAR file on the command line via `jar -tvf your_jar.jar` to make sure the enum class in fact made it in there?

Comment: Can not predict it without looking at the source code, however access modifier might be the issue here. Remember that default access means only visible to classes within the package and inherited class. @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I don't think private is allowed for a top level class level unless it is an inner class ;)

Comment: Yes , Jar Contains the class file , Enum class has access modifier of Public type , Enum constructor can't be public , hence it's of default type

Comment: Please post the output of `jar tf your.jar`, the code of your class, the code that uses your class and the specific error you're getting.
If you're using an IDE then a screenshot showing imported libraries, ideally showing that the class is actually in the library you import.  
My guess is that you probably import a wrong JAR (like an older version).

Comment: @lexicore I have added jar tf output and the class.  I am just trying to import this class , and it is not visible for the new project

Comment: @priyas I understand your problem but you need to provide input if you want to get help. The code which uses your enum and the IDE screenshot are still missing.

Comment: @lexicore added the class from where I am trying to call the class